# Restore APFS Volume on an external USB disk which does not mount

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, partition

I work with a MBP 15" (2019 eight core) and an USB HDD partitioned with an APFS encrypted volume.

Yesterday, after a regular power off of my MBP, I plugged in my external USB disk and I got an error message saying that Mac was unable to mount the disk and asking me to format it. In Disk Utility, this disk figure as Seagate ST4000LM024-2AN17V - USM external physical disk - Master Boot Record (MBR).
I tried from terminal to run `diskutil list` and that showed me the following:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                       0xEE                         2.2 TB     disk2s1
```

In the meantime, I found a software (iBoysoft Data Recovery) that had found my APFS encrypted partition and that is recovering my data, but I'm wondering how can I mount/restore this partition using terminal?

Comment: Please, any ideas? I'm really in a trouble ...

Comment: You mention that you are already able to recover your data, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you actually are looking for.